# Foundation 4 - making top-bar dropdowns work for ipad

Tags: ipad, zurb-foundation

I have a client that wants the desktop version of foundation 4's top bar to appear on the ipad instead of the mobile version. This is fine as their site only has a few sections, but each section has sub-pages and so the nav displays dropdowns for each link.

I modified the break point and the nav *looks* fine on the iPad, and tapping a parent link displays the submenu - but I can't get the dropdowns to close once one is open - you can switch between dropdowns, but tapping anywhere else on the screen makes the dropdown flash off and then it reappears.

I've tried adding some JS to catch clicks anywhere else on the document body, and to hide any visible sub menus, but it's not working, I still get the off/on flash - I can't see anywhere in the foundation.topbar.js that would be overriding it, but I also can't think of anywhere else in the code that would cause this.

Does anyone have any experience of getting these desktop-version menus to work nicely on an ipad? And before you say 'the ipad is a mobile device, you should use the mobile nav that works' - I already tried convincing the client of that and they didn't go for it :/

Comment: Not that this is much use, but I am looking to fix the same problem. If you happened to solve it, please let me know! I'll get back to you if I do, too.

Comment: I didn't solve it Desmond - if you do, I'd love to hear how you do it!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
  $('.top-bar-section ul li .parent-link.js-generated').show();
}
```

foundation already prepares the top level nav item to be shown in the dropdown of the mobile menu. You can use this also on desktop version of the menu on touch screens like iPad.

Andrea

Comment: This made it so my dropdown didn't even fire the first time on iPad